# Convers number ranges

Tags: c#, math, numbers

I need to convert a number that can be between 0 and 65535
to another number between -800 and 240

so if oldNumber = 0, then newNumber = -800

```
public static int ConvertA(int oldNumber)
{

}

newNumber = ConvertA(oldNumber);
```

and vise versa , so if it's -800 to 240 then convert it to 0 to 65535

```
public static int ConvertB(int oldNumber)
{

}
newNumber = ConvertB(oldNumber);
```

Comment: so if oldNumber = 0, then newNumber = 65535 ?

Comment: Can you explain better ? It's pretty unclear

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post some of your code along with expected outputs?

Comment: it means 0 is max value  which is "65535"

Comment: I think he wana do something like fx we have color part as float  0..1 and he want to get same color as byte 0...255 ... it' pretty simple math

Comment: 65535 is 0xFFFF which in 2's compliment is -1.  So you can use             int input = 0xFFFF; 
            int output = (input + 1) & 0xFFFF;

Comment: nx = ns + bx/((be - bs)/(ne - ns)) ? where bx is nuber from bs...be and new section is ns...ne (bs - base section start, ne - new section end, etc)

Comment: Yes, simple linear conversion is what I was after.

Comment: hehe instead bx should be (bx - bs) which make the same answer as yours as a/(b/c) = a*c/b

Answer (score 0):

You have two integer intervals `A = [0, 65535]` and `B = [-800, 240]` and you want a mapping `f: A -> B`.

You seem to have stated that you also want the constraints:

- `f(0) == 240`
- `f has a inverse transform g`.

Since the number of elements in `A` (65536) is greater than the number of elements in `B` (1041), by the pigeon hole principle `f` cannot be `injective` (there must be `x`, `y` in `A` such that `f(x) == f(y)`).

As a result, `f` cannot have a inverse transform `g`. Which means the constraints cannot derive a solution. **That is, your question does not have a solution**.

Also, note that your transform cannot be `linear`. If it was linear it would need to satisfy `f(a*x) == a*f(x)` for every `a` and `x`, and this cannot be true because if we choose `x == 0` and `a == 2`, we have `f(2*0) == f(0) == 240 == 2 * f(0) == 480`, which is clearly an absurd.

Linearity requires `f(0) == 0`.

---

**But then, lets be flexible and change your constraints...**

So lets assume than that we do not need an inverse and that f does not need to be linear. Perhaps a mapping such as

`f(x) := max((-x) + 240, -800)` satisfies your needs.

In that case:

- `f(0) == max(240, -800) == 240`, the first constraint is met
- We can define `g: B -> A` as `g(x) := (-x) + 240`, which satisfies `g(240) == 0` and is such that `f(g(x)) == max((x - 240) + 240, -800) == max(x, -800) == x`, meaning `f` is a inverse of `g` when constrained to the `Range` of `g`.

Bottom line, the following solutions might be suitable:

- **`f(x) := max((-x) + 240, -800)`**
- **`g(x) := (-x) + 240`**

Just don't expect linearity and/or inverse transforms.

---

Using that assumption, there you have it:

```cs
public static int ConvertA(int oldNumber)
{
    if(oldNumber < 0 || oldNumber > 65535)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    return Math.Max((-oldNumber) + 240, -800);
}
int newNumber = ConvertA(oldNumber);
```

```cs
public static int ConvertB(int oldNumber)
{
    if(oldNumber < -800 || oldNumber > 240)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    return -oldNumber + 240;
}
int newNumber = ConvertB(oldNumber);
```

Keep in mind that, as discussed in the begging, that `ConvertB(ConvertA(65535))` is not `65535`, as `ConvertB` is not the inverse of `ConvertA`

Answer (score -1):

I have figured it out.

```
private static int Convert(int OldMax, int OldMin, int NewMax, int NewMin, int OldValue)
{
   int NewValue = 0;
   int NewRange = 0;
   int OldRange = 0;

    OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin);
    if (OldRange == 0)
    NewValue = NewMin;
    else
    {
       NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin);
       NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin;
    }

    return NewValue;
}
```